# Creating a regular expression that replaces strings in quotes with empty strings

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

How can I create a regular expression that finds the text wrapped in `"""` or `'''` for example:

```
hello """
long text here,
e.g. a private SSH key
"""
this is a name for testing

'''
this is another multi-line 
stuff.
'''
```

I want to get the output like:

```
hello
this is a name for testing
```

With all the text that are in `"""` or `'''` replaced with an empty string.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `"""|'''` as delimiters (with a `\1` back-reference for the closing one), a non-greedy match-all (`.*?`) and the `s` (dot-all) and `g` (global) flags.

Remove leading and trailing white-space with `trim()`.

```js
const str = `hello """
long text here,
e.g. a private SSH key
"""
this is a name for testing

'''
this is another multi-line 
stuff.
'''`

console.log(str.replace(/("""|''').*?\1/gs, "").trim());
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try a regex replacement targeting all multiline quoted terms.  We will use dot all mode to ensure that the matches occur across newlines.

```js
var input = `
hello """
long text here,
e.g. a private SSH key
"""
this is a name for testing

'''
this is another multi-line 
stuff.
'''`;
var output = input.replace(/""".*?"""|'''.*?'''/sg, '').trim();
console.log(output);
```